# Problems selecting specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I have the following table:

```
Id      revenue LogAt       playlog LogAt     creds playlog Id
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:37    13  178849374
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:38    13  178849795
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:39    13  178850630
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:41    13  178851326
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:33    13  178847056
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:34    13  178847796
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:36    13  178848715
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:32    13  178846609
9673648 26.02.2013 13:46    26.02.2013 13:32    13  178846250
```

Its actually much longer, having much more "groups" of Id's which are listed multiple times like this one, the only difference in each group being the playlog logat times and the playlog id's.

Now in the given example, I need to select the row where playlog logat is timed at 13:41.
also, for all other group of id's, I need the row with the "newest" playlog logat row.
of all these rows, creds should sum up.

I take it that I have to filter this 1 row for every group of id's through the times, but I don't know how.
Maybe something with min()/max()?

My rdbms is Microsoft sql server management studio.

The table is a result of following joins:

```
select *
from credits
inner join user on credits.userid = user.id
inner join sessionlog on user.id = sessionlog.userid
inner join playlog on sessionlog.id = playlog.sessionlogid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the max of `playlog logat` as a CTE or subquery, and then join that to the full table to get the rest of the row data.

```
WITH max_cte
AS
(
  SELECT Id, MAX([playlog LogAt]) AS MaxLogAt
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT max_cte.Id, max_cte.MaxLogAt, 
  tablename.[revenue LogAt], tablename.creds, tablename.[playlog Id]
FROM max_cte
INNER JOIN tablename
  ON max_cte.Id = tablename.Id
  AND max_cte.MaxLogAt = tablename.[playlog LogAt]
```

Comment: hm ok, to get the large table, i have to join 4 smaller tables. where can i do that in your code?

Comment: That might be a problem, or it might not. To know for sure, we'll need you to add more detail to your question. Please show your tables and what you're doing now to join them.

Comment: there is a credits-table that i inner join with an user-table on credits.userid = user.id. then i inner join that with a sessionlog-table on sessionlog.userid = u.id. and then i inner join that with a playlog-table on playlog.sessionlogid = sessionlog.id. the problem i, after joining a player that for example payed for something on level 5 once, and played 10 other levels after that within the same session, will get marked as "has payed" on all the other 10 levels as well.

Comment: i guess that happens because the credits-table only contains the user-id. and EVERY playlog (for every level played) contains the user-id after joining with sessionlog. hence, every level played gets the "has payed" set to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's very hard to follow something like this in a comment. Is the "table" you reference above actually a view? Will you please update your question with the definition, complete with all of those joins?

Comment: yes it is a view, after all these joins. updated the question, hope it help.

Comment: I would just apply it to the completed view. It's still hard for be to answer how to do this before doing the joins because I don't know how the tables are structured, but the gist is to get the user id and "MaxLogAt" from the appropriate table -- probably `playlog` -- and then add MaxLogAt as a second join condition to join `max_cte` back to `playlog`. If that's not clear enough, please create a copy of your table structure as a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)